# Librosa Constant Q Transform (CQT) contains defects at the beginning and ending of the spectrogram

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, librosa

Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from librosa import cqt

s = np.linspace(0,1,44100)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*1000*s)
fmin=500

cq_lib = cqt(x,sr=44100, fmin=fmin, n_bins=40)

plt.imshow(abs(cq_lib),aspect='auto', origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('Time Steps')
plt.ylabel('Freq bins')
```

It will give a spectrogram like this

[image]

When you look closely at the beginning and the ending of the spectrogram, you can see that there's some defects there.

When plotting out only the first and the last time step, you can see the frequency is not correct.

### First Frame

```
plt.plot(abs(cq_lib)[:,0])
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlabel('Freq bins')
plt.tick_params(labelsize=16)
```

[image]

### Last and 2nd Last frame comparison

```
plt.plot(abs(cq_lib)[:,-1])
plt.plot(abs(cq_lib)[:,-2])
plt.legend(['last step', '2nd last step'], fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.xlabel('Freq bins')
plt.tick_params(labelsize=16)
```

[image]

### My attempt to solve it

According to my knowledge, it should be due to padding and putting the `stft` window at the center. But it seems `cqt` doesn't support the argument `center=False`.

```
cq_lib = cqt(x,sr=44100, fmin=fmin, n_bins=40,center=False)
```

> TypeError: cqt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'center'

Am I doing anything wrong? How to make `center=False` in `cqt`?

Comment: Which version of librosa is this on?

Comment: I am using librosa 0.7.0. Do you get other behaviours when using other versions?

Comment: I do not know. I just saw in the changelog for 0.7.0 that CQT had some changes. So might be worth a quick check

Comment: @jonnor I could replicate this in librosa 0.6.3 so I don't think it's a version issue. I think it is just what happens at the edge of a signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want to try out `pad_mode` which is supported in [cqt](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.cqt.html).  If you checkout the np.pad [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), you can see available options (or see the end of this post).  With the `wrap` option, you get a result like this, though I suspect the phase is a mess, so you should make sure this meets your needs.  If you are always generating your own signal, you could trying using the `<function>` instead of one of the available options.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from librosa import cqt

s = np.linspace(0,1,44100)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*1000*s)
fmin=500

cq_lib = cqt(x,sr=44100, fmin=fmin, n_bins=40, pad_mode='wrap')

plt.imshow(abs(cq_lib),aspect='auto', origin='lower')
plt.xlabel('Time Steps')
plt.ylabel('Freq bins')
```

[image]

If you look at the first frame and last two frames you can see it now looks much better.  I tried this with librosa 0.6.3 and 0.7.0 and the results were the same.

[image]

[image]

Try some of the options and hopefully you can find one of the padding options that will do the trick:
`np.pad` [options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):
`‘constant’, ‘edge’, ‘linear_ramp’, ‘maximum’, ‘mean’,‘median’,‘minimum’, ‘reflect’, ‘symmetric’, ‘wrap’, ‘empty’, <function>`

Comment: I see. But I am thinking about what causes two peaks in the beginning step. Even if you do padding, the majority of the single would still be of the frequency 1000Hz. But why does the first frame got less signal at 1000Hz, instead, two peaks appears at the adjutant locations. I will like to also know what is the physics behind it.

Comment: If I'm interpreting it correctly, the two waves represented in your graph of the first frame, with appropriate phase relationship, would approximate the onset of the signal.